# pass value from object to another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const small = {
  a: 1,
  func: function(b, c, d) {
    return this.a + b + c + d;
  },
};

const large = {
  a: 5,
};

small.func(2, 3, 5);
```

I need to access a: 5 from large object into small object. currently small.func(2,3,5) is giving 11 as output. I need to get 15 as ouput.

Comment: You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to bind the `this` to `large`

Comment: better to put the method outside of the object and then call it for any object you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this-

```
function func(b, c, d) {
    return this.a + b + c + d;
  }
const small = {
  a: 1,
  
};

const large = {
  a: 5,
};

func.call(large, 2,3, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) here as:

```
const result = small.func.call(large, 2, 3, 5);
```

What above statement means is that *You are taking the function(or can say borrowing) `small.func` function and applying in the context of `large` object with argument 2, 3, 5.*

```js
const small = {
  a: 1,
  func: function(b, c, d) {
    return this.a + b + c + d;
  },
};

const large = {
  a: 5,
};

   const result = small.func.call(large, 2, 3, 5);
// const result = small.func.apply(large, [2, 3, 5]);
console.log(result);
```